# Table-layout fixed and full row colspan with dynamic columns

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I was trying to set table columns width but I noticed that when it works in FF, it is completely ignored in Chrome/Edge. Fix is quite easy - set table-layout to fixed.

It made all browsers respect columns width but suddenly rows with just one cell which was required to be span accross all columns started to behave badly. As they had colspan set to 20 (more than actual columns) they started to actually span accross non-existing colums breaking layout.

The fix would also be easy - set colspan to actual number of columns. Unfortunatelly they were dynamic and changing depending from user to user. But I still need to have one cell to span across all table.

I could count number of columns every time I generate table and put it in colspan but it's way less than ideal solution. I should not have to implement this kind logic and mess with actual logic just for silly formating.

**Question**: how to make colspan to cover all columns in fixed layout table without specifying columns count every time table is generated?

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution or rather "dirty hack" which solves this issue. As there seems to be no way to do it with colspan I set:

- Table:

> table-layout: fixed;

- Table row requiring colspan to:

> height: 28;

- Table cell to colspan:

> position: absolute;
>   width: 100%;
>   line-height: 28px;
>   text-align: center;

This way even though theoretically cell covers only first column it also "floats" above whole row and as it has width set to 100% it covers it in full the same way it would with colspan set to number of columns.

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/abvL5jbd/][Demo]
```

Works in FF, Chrome, Edge.